# Incorrect Currency for Payment - Checkout showing EURO & £

Tags: multicurrency

I have 2 websites, 
**UK - Currency £** and 
**DE - Currency EURO**.  
All the prices on the DE website convert correctly into EUROs as expected. 
 When I get to the chechout, everything is in EURO except for the final payment amount which is showing in £ and when it goes to paypal or HSBC it passes across the value in £ instead of EURO!

[image]

I guess I am missing a setting somewhere???  Where else should I be looking for this setting?

`Configuration > Currency` is set correct for each website.